# Should I avoid using Unicode characters in variable names?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

The C# language specification says we can use Unicode characters in specifiers (class and variable names, etc.)

I went a long way doing this in my code. Since I live in Brazil, this includes lots of accented characters, with variable names such as `rotação`, `ângulo`, `máximo`, etc.

Every time a more "experienced" developers catches this, I am *strongly* advised to avoid it and change everything back. Otherwise a lot of kittens will die.

I went then a quite long way *undoing* it, but today I found some variables still named with accents, in methods written long ago, and no kitten died so far (at least not because of *that*).

Since my language (Portuguese) is accented, it would make a lot of sense if our codebase has those characters, since C# explicitly allows it.

Are there any <strike>sound</strike> *technical* reason not to use Unicode characters in C#/Visual Studio codebases?

Comment: I prefer, as a good habit, always use English names in each and every project. Then problem with accent disappears. The problem of understanding the code by current and future developers - disappears. The problem to publish this code on Stack Overflow - disappears.

Comment: If the code is going to be edited by people who are not fluent in Portuguese, then using variable names like that makes it difficult for them.  There is also the issue of similar-looking letters, as an example, is г the letter "r" or the Cyrillic character "Ge?"

Comment: You may also try to mix your code with RTL languages and have fun `string قيمة = "aa";`

Comment: Does anyone actually understood that I plan to use arbitrary unicode characters that do NOT belong to Portuguese? Like, "just for the fun of it", or whatever? C'mon, people...

Comment: This MSDN page answers the question: NO, there is no reason to avoid it, at least no Microsoft-related reason.
"_..you can use Arabic or Hebrew to name classes, functions, variables, properties, string literals, attributes, and so on. However, the editor does not support right-to-left reading order; text always starts at the left margin._"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIbrary/dc6bb2eh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: A good reason why you might want to include a Unicode character in a variable name: to satisfy [CA1704: Identifiers should be spelled correctly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1704-identifiers-should-be-spelled-correctly?view=vs-2019). While building a relationship-type enumeration, I added a member named `Fiancee`. Visual Studio's Code Analysis tool flagged this member with CA1704. I resolved the warning by changing its spelling to include an `e` with acute: `Fiancée`.

Answer (score 2):

What if you had to take over code written in Cyrillic?  Most developers are comfortable with standard Latin character sets.  They're easy to type on any keyboard.

I would recommend sticking to the simple set.

Comment: Are you suggesting me to use english wording, or use portuguese wording only without accents?

Comment: That's a more complicated question.  I may not know a word, but it's easier if I at least know how to type it.

Answer (score 2):

A few reasons why not to use Unicode variable names:

1. It makes it hard for people to type them
2. Some Unicode characters look very similar to non-native speaker (see the case of the Turkish I)
3. Some editors might not display them correctly
4. https://twitter.com/Stephan007/status/481001490463866880/photo/1

Comment: I edited the question: is there any TECHNICAL reason...? So far I have only seen "human factors", subjective reasons.

Comment: There's no technical reason.  The compiler doesn't care what you call a variable or what characters you use, only that they're legal and they're unique.  The only reasons that matter are the human factor ones, since your code will one day need to have another human being read it and maybe edit it.

Comment: The fact that someone's editor might not know how to read it is pretty technical.

Comment: @Namfuak My question explicitly refers to Visual Studio, so any developer is supposed to read the code in Visual Studio.

Comment: @TonyVitabile that seems to be THE real answer to the question: "There's no technical reason. The compiler doesn't care what you call a variable or what characters you use, only that they're legal and they're unique." You see, that ANSWERS my question, leting me free to CHOOSE which cost is higher. I can see some cost in a team composed 100% by portuguese-speaking developers trying to figure out if the variable `furacao` means "furacão" or "furação", for example.